# Sticky nav bar flickers when scrolling slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I’m currently stuck on an issue that’s happening with our sticky nav.

When a user scrolls down the screen very slowly our second navigation which is a sticky nav, flickers for some reason. I don’t know what it could be.

I’ve tried adding “-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);” to the “.affix” and ".affix-top" classes with no luck.

This issue is only happening on Chrome and Edge. Firefox, IE11 and Safari this issue does not occur thankfully.

What's causing this? How can/if this be resolved?

[Link to live page here.](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/forHome/products/free-tools.html)

Here’s the JS to the sticky nav:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
$('.full-width-anchorLinks').parent().addClass('full-browser-width-wrap');

if( $(".sticky").length ) {
    var $navbar = $(".sticky");
    var scrollTop     = $('body').scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $navbar.offset().top,
        distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop),
        anchor        = Math.round(distance);

    $navbar.affix({offset: {top: anchor} });

    var scrollSpyOffsetTotal = 0;
    // Header Height: onLoad (Use mainly for when scrollTop is 0)
    if ($(".globalHeaderV2, .consumerHeaderV2").length) {
        var headerHeight = $('.globalHeaderV2, .consumerHeaderV2').height();
        scrollSpyOffsetTotal += headerHeight;
    }
    // Nav Container Height: on page scroll
    if ($(".navbar-main-fixed, .nav-container.sticky").length) {
        var navContainer = $('.navbar-main-fixed, .nav-container.sticky').height();
        scrollSpyOffsetTotal += navContainer;
    }

    if ($(".affix-top, .affix").length) {
        var affixHeight = $('.affix-top, .affix').height();
        scrollSpyOffsetTotal += affixHeight;
    }

    if ($(".breadcrumb").length) {
        var breadcrumbHeight = $('.breadcrumb').height();
        scrollSpyOffsetTotal += breadcrumbHeight;
    }

    //If sticky breadcrumbs exist and tablet/desktop view point,
    $('body').addClass('scroll-main').scrollspy({target: '.navbar', offset: scrollSpyOffsetTotal});

    //On scroll change the top position of '.affix' based on sticky main nav and sticky breadcrumbs
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var totalOffset = 0;

        // Old consumer (forhome)/Business Header
        if ($(".navbar-main-fixed").length) {
            var navHeight = $(".navbar-main-fixed").height();
            totalOffset += navHeight;
        }

        // Consumer Header
        if ($(".nav-container.sticky").length) {
            var consumerNavHeight = $(".nav-container.sticky").height();
            totalOffset += consumerNavHeight;
        }

        if ($(".breadcrumb-fixed").length) {
            var breadcrumbHeight = $(".breadcrumb-fixed").height();
            totalOffset += breadcrumbHeight;
        }

        if ($(".sticky-sem-header").length) {
            var semHeaderHeight = $(".sticky-sem-header").height();
            totalOffset += semHeaderHeight;
        }

        // Desktop
        if ($(window).width() >= 1024) {
            $(".affix").css("top",totalOffset+"px");
        } else if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
            var mobileNavHeight = $('.navbar-main-fixed, .nav-container.sticky').height();
            $(".affix").css("top",mobileNavHeight+"px");
        }
    });
}

// Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
$(".anchorLinks a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();

        // Init destination var
        var dest = 0;
        var hash = this.hash;
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var headerHeight = 0;
        var navContainer = 0;
        var breadcrumbHeight = 0;

        // Header Height: onLoad (Use mainly for when scrollTop is 0)
        if ($(".globalHeaderV2, .consumerHeaderV2").length) {
            headerHeight = $('.globalHeaderV2, .consumerHeaderV2').height();
        }
        // Nav Container Height
        if ($(".navbar-main-fixed, .nav-container.sticky, .nav-sticky-wrapper").length) {
            navContainer = $('.navbar-main-fixed, .nav-container.sticky, .nav-sticky-wrapper').height();
        }

        // Affix (sticky nav)
        var affixHeight = $('.affix, .affix-top').height();

        if (scrollTop === 0) {
            // Desktop
            if ($(window).width() >= 1024) {
                if ($(".breadcrumb").length && ($(".breadcrumb ul.crumbs").css("display") != "none")) {
                    breadcrumbHeight = $('.breadcrumb').height();

                    // Exists When "supercrumb" is added
                    if ($(".breadcrumb .crumbs.supercrumb").length && ($(".breadcrumb ul.crumbs").css("display") != "none")) {
                        // Check if disruptor exists
                        if ($(".disruptorPanel").length && ($(".disruptorPanel").css("display") != "none")) {
                            disruptorPanel = $('.disruptorPanel').height();
                            dest = $(hash).offset().top - (disruptorPanel + headerHeight + breadcrumbHeight);
                        } else {
                            // W fixed breadcrumb
                            dest = $(hash).offset().top - (headerHeight + breadcrumbHeight + 106 + affixHeight);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // W/O Fixed breadcrumb
                        dest = $(hash).offset().top - (navContainer + breadcrumbHeight + 50 + affixHeight);
                    }
                } else {
                    dest = $(hash).offset().top - (headerHeight + affixHeight - 10);
                }
                // Mobile
            } else if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
                // Mobile Nav Container Height
                // Check Business Site/ Old forHome / Research Site for disruptor
                if ($(".disruptorPanel").length && $(".bottom-bar").length) {
                    navContainer = $('.bottom-bar').height();
                    disruptorPanel = $('.disruptorPanel').height();
                    dest = $(hash).offset().top - (headerHeight + navContainer + affixHeight - disruptorPanel);
                } else if ($(".bottom-bar").length) {
                    dest = $(hash).offset().top - (headerHeight + navContainer + affixHeight);
                }
                // New consumer
                if ($(".nav-container").length) {
                    dest = $(hash).offset().top - (headerHeight);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($(".breadcrumb-fixed").length && ($(".breadcrumb ul.crumbs").css("display") != "none")) {
                breadcrumbHeight = $('.breadcrumb-fixed').height();
                dest = $(hash).offset().top - (navContainer + breadcrumbHeight + affixHeight);

                // Remove breadcrumb height, since breadcrumb does not show on tablet wide and down
                if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
                    dest = $(hash).offset().top - (navContainer + affixHeight);
                }
            } else {
                dest = $(hash).offset().top - (navContainer + affixHeight);
            }
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.hash = hash;
        }, 300);

        // Scroll to destination - Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: dest}, 800);
    } // End if
});
});
```

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to debug minified site but I saw that it caused because .affix and .affix-top are added and removed one after the other (infinite loop).
In addition, there are lot of errors of "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')" in the console (clientlibs.min.js)

Comment: @AlonShmiel thanks for getting back. How can I resolve that?

Comment: 1. put a breakpoint in the window.scroll
2. make it flickers
3. You will see it called lot of times.

I guess there is a place that you add .affix and remove .affix-top and vise versa.
When you update the class, window.scroll is called.

Can you create a codepen that demonstrates it?

Comment: I can play with adding a breakpoint in window.scroll and see what happens. This site is built with adobe aem and there's lots of components that have to play nice with each other so to recreate it on Codepen might be difficult. Thank you! @AlonShmiel

Comment: I will try to debug it and let you know if I find something..

Comment: Thank you my friend! I'm left scratching my head with this since it's only really a chrome/edge issue. Any help is gladly appreciated! @AlonShmiel

Comment: @AlonShmiel Here's my code pen I'm messing with... still no luck recreating the issue on codepen. https://codepen.io/spidey677/pen/eYGqmep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it works, please make the next things:

1. Add position sticky (and other styles) to this element:

[image]

2A. Remove the code that toggle between .affix and .affix-top

OR:

2B 1. If you can't do step 2A, you can add this height instead (in order to make affix and affix-top to be with the same height):

[image]

2B 2. Remove position: fixed from affix and position static from affix-top (they don't need positions cause we set position to their parent)

In addition, I don't know if it's third party code or not but please try to not use !important property. It's hard to set style for those elements.

Comment: Looks like adding 'height: 76px;' to the 'anchorLinks' class did the trick. We just added a third party tool for accessibility so that's where the '!important' is coming from. Thank you! @AlonShmiel

Comment: Like! By the way, it's 76px in the parent because it contains border-top and border-bottom of 1px per border (74px + 1px + 1px).

Comment: Also this is the piece of js that's toggling between 'affix' and 'affix-top' classes.. "$navbar.affix({offset: {top: anchor} });"... I'm guessing maybe it's looking for a manual set height in the css in order to play nice. You're a JS ninja!